# Character matrix declaration and printing in C

Tags: c, character, declaration

I've tried to search for the answer but couldn't find anything ,at least not involing pointers etc.(want something basic because i just started programming in C and im trying to learn about character matrix)what am i doing wrong ?

(just trying to print what the character matrix)

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char ar['a','b','c'];
int i;

int main() {

    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%c",ar[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> error: ‘ar’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> printf("%c",ar[i]);

Thank you  for your time.

Comment: I'm sure how to declare an array is covered in every beginner's tutorial.

Comment: You accidentally declared an array of 99 elements (because `'c'` maps to 99 in ISO 8859-x and related code sets, including Unicode and MS code pages).  And didn't initialize it.  Your variable `i` should be inside `main()`; there is essentially no excuse for ever declaring a global variable `i`.  The array could be too.  I'm not clear why you get the undeclared error, unless there was a previous error that you're not reporting.

Comment: It's called an "array". A "matrix" is a mathematical term which can be implemented in C with arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *first* declare your array `ar`, and *then* initialize it.

This would work:

```
char ar[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```